# how to capture HTTPS packets using libtins?

Tags: c++, https

Im using **libtins** library for sniffing.
 The given example **http_requests.cpp** works for HTTP requests.
to capture https packets i tried using

`config.set_filter("tcp port 443");`

but didn't work

complete code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
#include "tins/tcp_ip/stream_follower.h"
#include "tins/sniffer.h"

using std::string;
using std::cout;
using std::cerr;
using std::endl;
using std::exception;

using boost::regex;
using boost::match_results;

using Tins::PDU;
using Tins::Sniffer;
using Tins::SnifferConfiguration;
using Tins::TCPIP::Stream;
using Tins::TCPIP::StreamFollower;



const size_t MAX_PAYLOAD = 3 * 1024;

regex request_regex("([\\w]+) ([^ ]+).+\r\nHost: ([\\d\\w\\.-]+)\r\n");

regex response_regex("HTTP/[^ ]+ ([\\d]+)");

void on_server_data(Stream& stream) {
    match_results<Stream::payload_type::const_iterator> client_match;
    match_results<Stream::payload_type::const_iterator> server_match;
    const Stream::payload_type& client_payload = stream.client_payload();
    const Stream::payload_type& server_payload = stream.server_payload();

    bool valid = regex_search(server_payload.begin(), server_payload.end(),
                              server_match, response_regex) &&
                 regex_search(client_payload.begin(), client_payload.end(),
                              client_match, request_regex);

    if (valid) {
        // Extract all fields
        string method = string(client_match[1].first, client_match[1].second);
        string url = string(client_match[2].first, client_match[2].second);
        string host = string(client_match[3].first, client_match[3].second);
        string response_code = string(server_match[1].first, server_match[1].second);
        // Now print them
        cout << method << " http://" << host << url << " -> " << response_code << endl;

        // Once we've seen the first request on this stream, ignore it
        stream.ignore_client_data();
        stream.ignore_server_data();
    }

    // Just in case the server returns invalid data, stop at 3kb
    if (stream.server_payload().size() > MAX_PAYLOAD) {
        stream.ignore_server_data();
    }
}

void on_client_data(Stream& stream) {
    // Don't hold more than 3kb of data from the client's flow
    if (stream.client_payload().size() > MAX_PAYLOAD) {
        stream.ignore_client_data();
    }
}

void on_new_connection(Stream& stream) {
    stream.client_data_callback(&on_client_data);
    stream.server_data_callback(&on_server_data);

    stream.auto_cleanup_payloads(false);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc != 2) {
        cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " <interface>" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    try {

        SnifferConfiguration config;

        config.set_immediate_mode(true);
         // Only capture TCP traffic sent from/to port 80
        config.set_filter("tcp port 443");
        // Construct the sniffer we'll use
        Sniffer sniffer(argv[1], config);

        cout << "Starting capture on interface " << argv[1] << endl;

        // Now construct the stream follower
        StreamFollower follower;

        follower.new_stream_callback(&on_new_connection);

        sniffer.sniff_loop([&](PDU& packet) {
            follower.process_packet(packet);
            return true;
        });
    }
    catch (exception& ex) {
        cerr << "Error: " << ex.what() << endl;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

how do i configure it to work for https protocol?

Comment: You need to explain what "but didn't work" means. Just posting code and no error message or proper description of how it didn't work will get the question closed as off topic.

Comment: it will stuck at  "Starting capture on interface"   no data printed after that

Comment: You should also include (edit the question) details of what you have already tried to debug the problem

Comment: well the regex is not matching

Comment: Why would you *expect* that regex to match the HTTPS data?  Isn't the whole point of encryption that the data stream doesn't resemble the payload?

Answer (score 2):

Just changing the port won't actually help.

While it will grab the packets it won't be able to do anything with them as they will be encrypted so none of the regexps will match.

Unless you have access to the private key from the server to decrypt the content then this code will never work.

Comment: then how does tcpdump gives the https data?

Comment: tcpdump doesn't give you any information about the content of the packet, only it's src/dest port/ip.